# nginx-ingress works well for /, but not for subpaths

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have setup a name based ingress controller, but it doesn't seem to work for anything other than `/`.

So `http://metabase.domain.com` works but `http://metabase.domain.com/style/app.css` does not.

This is my config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: domain
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "domain"
  name: domain-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: metabase.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: metabase
          servicePort: 80
  - host: jenkins.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 80
```

From the nginx.conf in the everything looks normal too. For some reason the nginx access and error logs are also empty so can't find anything from there too

Comment: I can offer a working example of using nginx ingress to map to apps on two different hosts using subdomains, both on the / path. https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/blob/6d27c3e65e4a6c79d0470f597813b1a5d14f7d27/activiti-cloud-full-example/values.yaml#L70 has keycloak and gateway on different hosts. They are in separate ingress resources (gw one is https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/blob/6d27c3e65e4a6c79d0470f597813b1a5d14f7d27/activiti-cloud-gateway/templates/ingress.yaml) and kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx is set but I am not sure what is the key difference.

Comment: @RyanDawson Can you share the yaml output of the ingress and the nginx deployment?

Comment: I can share the install steps https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/tree/6d27c3e65e4a6c79d0470f597813b1a5d14f7d27/activiti-cloud-full-example and you can do helm install with --dry-run --debug to just see what yaml it would generate.

Comment: @RyanDawson great thanks!

Comment: @RyanDawson The installation fails with `Error: no available release name found`

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3055#issuecomment-385439879 ?

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, there is no error in the log files, and everything looks normal from
your perspective. I may suggest to tune up ingress using annotations tags. 
I've checked [documentation of ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rewrite) and found that below annotations may help a bit.

In some scenarios, the exposed URL in the backend service differs from the specified path 
in the Ingress rule. Without a rewrite, any request will return 404. 
Set the annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target
```

to the path expected by the service.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something
```

If the Application Root is exposed in a different path and needs to be redirected, set the annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root
```

to redirect requests for /.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /app1
  name: approot
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: approot.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

If the application contains relative links, it is possible to add an additional annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url
```

that will prepend a base tag in the header of the returned HTML from the backend.

Answer (score 2):

I got around to solving this, turns out somehow there was another ingress on my namespace that was a very old version of the nginx controller. I cleared my cluster and relaunched my ingress. Things worked out. Thanks for all the help everyone!